# How to Auto Select Drop Down Box With Session value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, session-variables

```
        <select>
        <?php  foreach($result as $city) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $city->city_name; ?>" <?php if( strtolower($this->session->city) == strtolower($city->city_name)  ) { echo "selected"; }  ?>
        > <?php  echo $city->city_name; ?>  </option>
        <?php   } ?>
        </select>
```

Hi i am trying to auto select drop down box with the help of session but i am not able to select please some one help me out how could i auto select drop down box.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You should always provide the whole code, eg. in format of PHPFiddle.

Secondly, you should not mix HTML and PHP.

Also your problem cannot be deciphered from your question, because there might be several reasons. Like the city name could be in uppercase or capitalized in your session variable.

Your session variable might not be initialized with your session in the class constructor.

Also you might even not have a class at all, so the reference to $this would be obsolete.

But those aside, here's a code that might help you:

```
<?php
class MockSession {
    function __construct() {
    }
}
class Foo {

function __construct() {
    $this->session = new MockSession();
    $this->session->city = "Helsinki";
}
function printSelect() {
    $result = array("London","New York","Helsinki");

    echo '<select>';
    foreach ($result as $city) {
        $sel = '';
        echo $city." ".$this->session->city;
        if (strtolower($city)==strtolower($this->session->city)) {
        $sel = ' selected="selected" ';
        }
        echo '<option value="'.$city.'" '.$sel.'>'.$city.'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
}

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->printSelect();
?>
```

Comment: I am new to php can i know how can i place this in view .

Comment: I apologize not writing it in correct way i will always keep this in mind but still i am stuck in it :(

Comment: @SumitNair, Have you also tried to fetch the session variable from $_SESSION['city'], assuming that you are using normal session variable in PHP?

Comment: I am using codeigniter session , basically i am getting the session value when i echo it , it throws the correct value but while comparing its not working .

Answer (score 0):

If you got value of your session on the page then you have to just modify your code as `selected="selected"`. See updated code:

```
<select>
    <?php
        foreach ($result as $city) {
    ?>
        <option
            value="<?php echo $city->city_name; ?>"
            <?php if (strtolower($this->session->city) == strtolower($city->city_name)) {
                echo 'selected="selected"';
            }
            ?>> 
            <?php echo $city->city_name; ?>
        </option>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

But you should have to confirm first that you got value of `$this->session->city`.

Comment: i am getting value of session i tried echo $this->session->city i am getting the value from session but still its not working in drop down .@hatchet @minesh

Comment: if i am writing <select>
    <?php
        foreach ($result as $city) {
    ?>
        <option
            value="<?php echo $city->city_name; ?>"
            <?php if (strtolower('hyderabad') == strtolower($city->city_name)) {
                echo 'selected="selected"';
            }
            ?>> 
            <?php echo $city->city_name; ?>
        </option>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</select> it works my session value is same as i mentioned in comment i am not able to compare session value with drop down city .

Comment: @SumitNair Can you please provide your full page code here? So I can give you exact solution as soon as possible. Because according to above your code in comment, it should work.